# How to compare seasonality between time series?

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, seasonality

I have data like this:

|  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 0.03 | -0.07 | -0.62 | 0.26 | 0.47 | 0.01 | 0.54 | 0.41 | -0.38 | 0.50 | -0.84 | -0.30 |
| nx | 0.23 | 0.45 | 1.12 | 0.45 | 0.53 | 0.95 | 0.56 | -0.79 | -1.68 | -0.12 | -0.68 | -1 |

This is the result of the `decompose(tes$seasonal)` in R. Its a table of time series that I filtered by a variable, people with x, or people without x. I had a dataframe with a time variable, I created a time series filtering how many observations have that characteristic, and I put them this way. Then i noticed that people that use x, need less tests some months that people who doesn't use x. For example in March, for x is negative, and for nx is positive...

The thing is, I want to prove if there is diference in the time distribution between using x or not. So i thought that maybe as this is categorical(?) data, I can use Chi-squared, but I have no clue and I've met a dead end.

So maybe this has another name that I'm missing and I can learn, any tips?

Comment: I would start by generating autocorrelation plots for the two time series in question. If you observe a similar seasonality pattern in terms of correlation strength across certain time lags - then this could indicate that the seasonality patterns across the two series are similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MichaelGrogan , I understand that if the ACF comes out similar in both time series, we find a relationship, but if it doesn't come out similar, I can't deny that there is some relationship using the ACF, right?

Comment: It indicates that seasonality patterns across the two series are similar - but this does not necessarily mean the time series themselves are related. If you wanted to go further than seasonality, then you could use a cointegration test to determine if any correlations are meaningful or simply due to chance.